# Health insurance at 18

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, florida

I turned 18 a few weeks ago and live in Florida. I live with my mother, and I've been waiting for years for her to get insurance, but never does. As it is, we are a low-income family. I've had insurance with Humana before, but according to my mother, they kept canceling us.

It's difficult for me to find information about all of this, so I was wondering if it would be possible for me to get insurance without having to interact with my mother, pay annual fees, or be at risk of getting screwed over.

Comment: Be sure to read all the resources [here](https://www.healthcare.gov/young-adults/coverage/).

Comment: Are you asking how to get free insurance? (without having to...pay annual fees)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to get insurance without interacting with your mother. One way would be to find a job that offers health insurance. You could also get health insurance through your college or university (assuming you attend one). In addition, you could get health insurance through the [Affordable Care Act](https://www.healthcare.gov/young-adults/coverage/).

However, it is difficult to say that you won't pay "annual fees" since all those options above require some sort of premium. In addition, being "at risk of getting screwed over" all depends on what you need from health insurance and what kind of coverage you elect to purchase. Health insurance has gotten very complicated and you'll need to look at all the fine print before purchasing.